# Making guitar pro usable on a 4k monitor

Tags: guitar-pro

I recently got a new laptop with a 4k monitor and the picture is unbelievable!  The only problem is a lot of programs I used to use before will not scale properly to the new screen resolution.  Guitar pro is particularly bad... and I have not found a way to make the program even usable on my new laptop.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:
[image]

The buttons are all tiny and the text at the bottom is not scaling properly.  Has anyone attempted to use guitar pro on a high resolution monitor and been successful?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

### EDIT:

I know I can get it to look right by changing my computer's default resolution to 1920 x 1080, but that will change the resolution for ALL programs and completely defeats the purpose of having a 4k monitor so I don't consider that to be a solution.

### EDIT 2:

At the time of asking this question Guitar Pro 6 was the latest version. With Guitar Pro 7 4k resolution is now supported and it looks and sounds great!

Comment: Have you tried changing the display scaling?  It increases the size of text and UI elements while keeping the resolution high.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff629368.aspx

Comment: See this thread:
[reddit thread on using manifest](https://m.reddit.com/r/Guitar/comments/4q6ilm/discussion_fix_for_guitar_pro_6_on_windows_10/)

Comment: Here is a 100% working method [How to create manifest file][1]https://gist.github.com/cgarst/4fcf0d10145ced1626aef9934553cf9a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I contacted Guitar Pro support and they confirmed that there is no way to make guitar pro effectively work right on a 4k monitor.

As a work around I wrote a script that changes the screen resolution to 1080p for me and logs me out automatically so the change is applied.

They did, however, state that Guitar Pro 7 would have this kind of high resolution support! :)

Comment: Guitar Pro 7 does have that support and it is fully operational. I've already updated my GP for a small price, I recommend you do it too.

Comment: I already did too. :) at the time of posting this question gp7 was not available yet.

Comment: If I were you I would edit the question and answer to have people understand that it's about Guitar Pro 6 and not some other version.

Answer (score 2):

I tried several methods found in the internet regarding bad scaling issues in other programs like photoshop. Unfortunatelly none of them solves the problem with Guitar Pro 6. Finally I installed Guitar pro 5, that surprisingly DOES SCALE AT THE RIGTH SIZE and is usable again. The only problem is that W10 scaling make everithing blurry, but this is easy solved using Windows 8.1 scaling method (I used a small free program called XPWindows 10 dpi fix"). So... Back to GP5, Back to W8.1... I´m going to build an abandonware chamber just in case ;)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by right clicking the guitarpro.exe, properties, compatibility tab. Then click the box next to override high DPI scalling behavior and select scalling done by: system. worked perfectly for me. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the lower left corner of the box that holds your tab sheet. Click on it and there will be %s and at the bottom say Fit to Screen, in the case of 4k, Fit to Width as that 4k is the measurement of width at that resolution. It appears its an internal scaling system independent of the desktop scaling.